# c++ begin and end not working

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ifstream myfile (argv[1]);
  char ch;
  char operator_symbols[]={'+','-','*','<','>','&','.',
                               '@','/',':','=','~','|','$',
                               '!','#','%','^','_','[',']',
                               '{','}','\"','`','?'
                              };
  while(!myfile.eof())
    {
      myfile.get(ch);
      if(isalpha(ch))
    {
      cout << "isalpha " << ch << endl; 
    }
      else if(isdigit(ch))
    {
      cout << "is num " << ch << endl;
    }
      else if(find(begin(operator_symbols), end(operator_symbols), ch) != end(operator_symbols))
    {
      cout << "is operator sym" << ch << endl;
    }
      else if(ch == '(' || ch == ')' || ch == ';' || ch == ',')
    {
      cout << "is punctuation " << ch << endl;
    }
      else if (isspace(ch))
    {
      cout << "is space " << ch << endl;
    }
    }
}
```

The error, which is related to the if condition which tries to find a character match in the operator symbols array.  :

```
****@*****:~/Documents/ABC$ g++ lexer.cpp -o lexer
lexer.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
lexer.cpp:30:42: error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope
       else if(find(begin(operator_symbols), end(operator_symbols), ch) != end(operator_symbols))
                                          ^
lexer.cpp:30:65: error: ‘end’ was not declared in this scope
       else if(find(begin(operator_symbols), end(operator_symbols), ch) != end(operator_symbols))
```

I have included algorithm and iterator. Yet the compiler fails to compile. Please help! I've already tried to google this.

Comment: Perhaps try compiling with `-std=c++11`. `std::begin` for c-style arrays is a c++11 feature.

Comment: Where do I write that in the execution line?

Comment: Something like `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main`

Comment: yea it worked! thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `std::begin` and `std::end` with traditional C arrays was introduced in C++11, so you need to add `-std=c++11` to your compiler invocation.

Answer (score -1):

tyr to use this:

```
#include <vector>

char str[]={'+','-','*','<','>','&','.',
                           '@','/',':','=','~','|','$',
                           '!','#','%','^','_','[',']',
                           '{','}','\"','`','?'
                            };
vector<char> operator_symbols;
operator_symbols.push_back(str);

if(find(operator_symbols.begin(), operator_symbols.end(), ch) !=        operator_symbols.end())
```

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: begin() and end() are the standard function of vector，and they are called without parameters.you just have defined a array of char,but it dosen't have begin() and end() methods.So you must declare a new vector object 'operator_symbols',then puch array srt[] back to operator_symbols,then you can called its own methods ,such as begin() and end().

Comment: This will not even compile, as you are trying to push a char[] into a vector of char.

Comment: I understand.you can use this one :push_back('+'),then finish what you want to put one by one.